# Disable Git LFS for a remote

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to push to a second remote that doesn't support Git LFS. Is there a way to disable Git LFS for a specific remote using `git config`?

Comment: Workaround: `git push --no-verify` will skip the pre-push hook which triggers Git LFS

Comment: I know you can set a separate `lfsurl` for each `[remote]` in your `.git/config` --> did you try just having one without the `lfsurl`?

Comment: @danf If you don't have it, it defaults to the same server. If you set it to blank, you get a *missing protocol: ""* error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The workaround given by amiuhle works fine for me:

```
git push --no-verify
```

It prevents the pre-push hook of git lfs from trying to upload the files. So link-files are committed, but the actual binaries are missing.

Comment: This works for me, but I am curious about the question asked: is there something I can do with `git config` that will make `git push` work like `git push --no-verify` so I can use scripts as-is for pushing all my repos.

Comment: I got `LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".`

Comment: Note: as stated in the answer, this disables the (client-side) `pre-push` hook, but *not* the (server-side) `pre-receive` hook. Most git servers (e.g. GitLab) implement such a hook to check for missing LFS objects, as reported by @AvinShum